# What does it mean "Decreases Linearly"?

Tags: probability, nonlinear-system

From Hozmann, 1991 Design and Validation of Computer Protocols (no it's not networks):

The error model provided by the binary symmetric channel predicts that
the probability of a series of at least n contiguous error-free bit transmissions, called
an ‘‘error-free interval’’ (EFI), is equal to:

$$Pr(\operatorname{EFI} \geq n) = (1 - b)^n $$

where $b$ is the long-term average bit error rate.

The probability decreases linearly with the length of the interval. Similarly, the pro-
bability that the duration of a burst exceeds n bits decreases linearly with n

---

What could the author mean with "decreases linearly"? Is it about the derivative (as $b$ is a constant and $n$ a variable it would be $n \times (1 - b)$) or anything else?

Comment: In optimisation-adjacent fields, especially when talking about error a quantity $a_n$ "decreasing linearly" often means that the *logarithm* of $a_n$ decreases linearly, ie $a_n \leq e^{-An}$ for some $A > 0$. In classical error analysis, this can be interpreted as the number of correct bits being asymptotically linear in $n$.